# Use semaphore in C

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm learning how to use semaphore in C (linux).

I would like to ask you:

How to determine whether the order will be executed immediately , or will you wait?

[Example](http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs354s00/classes/code/SleepBarber.src.html) I take to sleeping barber:

In function:

```
    void *customer(void *number) {
    int num = *(int *)number;

    // Leave for the shop and take some random amount of
    // time to arrive.
    printf("Customer %d leaving for barber shop.\n", num);
    randwait(5);
    printf("Customer %d arrived at barber shop.\n", num);

    // Wait for space to open up in the waiting room...
    sem_wait(&waitingRoom);
    printf("Customer %d entering waiting room.\n", num);

    // Wait for the barber chair to become free.
    sem_wait(&barberChair);

    // The chair is free so give up your spot in the
    // waiting room.
    sem_post(&waitingRoom);

    // Wake up the barber...
    printf("Customer %d waking the barber.\n", num);
    sem_post(&barberPillow);

    // Wait for the barber to finish cutting your hair.
    sem_wait(&seatBelt);

    // Give up the chair.
    sem_post(&barberChair);
    printf("Customer %d leaving barber shop.\n", num);
}
```

On line `sem_wait(&waitingRoom);` is possible check waiting - true false?

I mean:

```
int time = sem_wait(&waitingRoom);
if(time != 0)
 printf("YOU MUST WAIT!");
```

OR

```
   int i = isSemaphoreFree()...
```

I hope, you understand me, sorry for my english :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `sem_trywait()` [sem_...  docs](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait)

This will return immediately with an error if the semaphore is currently blocked.

Comment: then..is possible to make sleep loop: `while(sem_trywait()==-1)sleep(5);` ?

Comment: @tilefrae, check for the -1 in an `if` and `perror` to see the error.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils sorry i dont understand you,, :-)